# How do I filter an empty array that has a white space?

Tags: java, arrays, hash

```
        String[][][] a=new String[5][5][5];
        HttpSession session = request.getSession();
        char[][] split = null;


        split=(char[][]) session.getAttribute("chardata");
        int[][][] plaint = (int[][][]) session.getAttribute("root");
        int r1=plaint.length;
        for (int i = 0; i < r1; i++) {
            int r2=plaint[i].length;
            for (int j = 0; j < r2; j++) {
                int r3=plaint[i][j].length;
                for (int k = 0; k < r3; k++) {
                    if(plaint[i][j][k]!=0){
                        a[i][j][k]= sha256(Integer.toString(plaint[i][j][k]));
                        out.println("data:"+split[i][j]+" <br> hash:" + a[i][j][k]+"<br>");

                    }
                }
                session.setAttribute("hashed",a);
                out.println(" <br><br>");
            }out.println(" <br>");
        }
        out.println("</body>");
        out.println("</html>");
        RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("redirection");
        rd.forward(request,response);
```

This is my servlet.

Sha256 hashes the value and returns a hex string  to a[][][].

A part of the output is:

> data:s
>   hash:d6d824abba4afde81129c71dea75b8100e96338da5f416d2f69088f1960cb091
>
> data:h
>   hash:ad48ff99415b2f007dc35b7eb553fd1eb35ebfa2f2f308acd9488eeb86f71fa8
>
> data:
>   hash:ad48ff99415b2f007dc35b7eb553fd1eb35ebfa2f2f308acd9488eeb86f71fa8

The variable plaint[][][] has empty values that are sent to be hashed too. I am not able to filter out these empty values. It seems like it has a white space in it but the system does not consider this as white space. It does not consider the value as null either.

Split[][] has the same problem too as it is derived from plaint[][][]. It has the values that are entered by the user and a character ' ' as the remaining index values

How do i filter it out?

Comment: Use debugger and find out what value it has. If you're sure it's a whitespace try Character.isWhitespace method.

Comment: Tried it. Debugger shows value as ' ' . Character.isWhitespace returns false.

Comment: Then there is no value, the array is empty, try `array.length != 0`

Comment: The array is not empty.  split[0][0]=s,split[0][1]=h,split[0][2]='  '.

Comment: What is hexadecimal value of the character?

Comment: The hex value of ' ' is 0000

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The character that has ' ' means that it is null (/u0000). So using:

```
if(split[i][j]!=0)
```

to check if it is NULL can solve the problem.